# Wildfly Clustering Does not work with web-fragment.xml

Tags: java, wildfly, web.xml, high-availability, web-fragment

I am trying to setup a clustering environment with Wildfly-10.

I have a `web-fragment.xml` for general purpose configuration and a `web.xml` for project specific configuration. With these configurations, clustering does not work.

But if I delete `web-fragment.xml` and move its content to `web.xml`, everything works fine.

I wonder what is the reason of this. Any idea?

Comment: delete and move what? what part of configuration?

Comment: As I understand, I have to add <distributable/> to both of web.xml and web-fragment.xml. What is the reason of this? Why just putting to web.xml is not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing `</distributable>` tag to both `web.xml` and `web-fragment.xml` has solved the problem.